# Did I get over engineering?

Tags: c#, solid-principles

Consider the code snippet :

```
switch (sectionType) {
        
      case "AConfig": 
      maxSize=config.Value.AConfig.MaxSize; 
      break; 

      case "BConfig": 
      maxSize = config.Value.BConfig.MaxSize; 
      break;

      case "CConfig": maxSize = config.Value.CConfig.MaxSize; 
      break;

      case " ...." 
      break; ,.... }
```

It is possible that the number of cases will be added during the expansion of the program ...
Due to the open / close principles, I do not want to use the switch case
Is there a way to make this piece dynamic, for example

```
config.Value."sectionType".MaxSize
```

"I am also using config to read the appconfig.json file"

Comment: You are much cleaner ways you could write that code but they don't involve LINQ or dynamic simply because they are not applicable to that snippet.

Comment: @ AluanHaddad : Can you give me an example of other methods?

Comment: Well, stop repeating yourself and use local variables for   starters

Comment: Well, why do you think, that dynamic linq solve your question? Wrapping repeated code for `maxSize` and `allowedExtensions` into `Func` delegate and passing a property as parameter may be helpful

Comment: `config.Value.FileUploadConfig.` - `CategoryConfig/SpecialShowConfig/BrandConfig` - so what are these types? Do you control them? Where is `sectionType` coming from?

Comment: @farshid Do the classes holding `MaxSize` and `AllowedExtensions` implement an interface (or have a base class) defining this properties?

Comment: You want "a better way", can you explain your issues with the current code?

Comment: @farshid You might want to ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but check the help pages there first to see, if it is on-topic and how you should write your question.

Comment: What's the point of editing the question if you're not addressing the comments in your edits?

Comment: @ZoharPeled : 
I'm really sorry to be so beginner. I'm actually looking for a dynamic phrase similar to dynamic linq

Comment: What is the type of `FileUploadConfig` and `CategoryConfig`, etc. inside?

Comment: That's not something to be sorry about. However the comments asking you to clarify your code are an attempt to help you, you should try to address them in your edits

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean by  _"I'm actually looking for a dynamic phrase similar to dynamic linq"_. Can you explain the thought behind that?

Comment: @Farshid It's not a good idea to make every thing dynamic and unreadable ! before any modification you should first of all consider pros and cons.

Comment: @AluanHaddad : My goal is to change the code at runtime based on user input. Perhaps the solution is to use reflection

Comment: _"Perhaps the solution is to use reflection"_ @farshid I cannot imagine that code such as what you've shown could possibly justify the maintainability and security costs of such an approach.

Comment: @AluanHaddad : My goal is to follow the principle
is open / closed (SOLID).
SectionTypes may expand during application development I do not want to have a new case "new Case"

Comment: Just use a `Dictionary<string, int>` or something. Your application has a complexity budget, whether you know it or not. Don't spend it here.

Comment: @AluanHaddad : 
Anyway, thank you for taking the time

Comment: I do not know, but I feel that my questions were very ridiculous and stupid

Comment: Not exactly. Just learn the basics first.

Comment: @AluanHaddad : 
I finally found the solution
Strategy pattern design should be used.

Comment: @farshid you do not need one. That's overengineering for such a simple code. You can use dynamic `sectionType` there with different syntax, and avoid conditions. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I prefer to use `if, else if, else` statement:

```
if (sectionType.Equals("CategoryConfig")){
   maxSize = config.Value.FileUploadConfig.CategoryConfig.MaxSize;
}
else if (sectionType.Equals("SpecialShowConfig")){
   maxSize = config.Value.FileUploadConfig.SpecialShowConfig.MaxSize;
}
else if(sectionType.Equals("BrandConfig")){
   maxSize = config.Value.FileUploadConfig.BrandConfig.MaxSize;     
}
...
else{
 // here default case
}
```

From **my personal** point of view this is more readable then switch. Not only but in this case you have a "short circuit" evaluation (in switch you have to evaluate all casistics before `break` statement) so I think this solution is more efficient.

Comment: :I'm looking for something like this: config.Value.FileUploadConfig. "SectionType" .MaxSize

Comment: Ciao, if `config.Value.FileUploadConfig` is a JSON you can do: `config.Value.FileUploadConfig[sectionType].MaxSize`

Comment: No, in c# you can't do `config.Value.FileUploadConfig[sectionType].MaxSize`. It's a little bit complicated and you have to involve some classes. Take a look to [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-json-in-C-Sharp/) guide.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an enum (assuming `maxSize` is an integer) in the `FileUploadConfig` file, like this:

```
public enum ConfigMaxSize 
{
    CategoryConfig = 1234,
    SpecialShowConfig = 999999,
    BrandConfig = 42
}
```

Your code would then become:

```
maxSize = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConfigMaxSize), sectionType);
```

Of course, this wont work if `maxSize` isn't an `int`

**Edit**: Don't forget to close this question when your problem is solved and if possible, add in the way you fixed in your original question for others who stumble on the same problem.